# TurtleBot Output Power

Tags: ros, turtlebot, turtlebot-arm

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to power an PhantomX arm from my recently purchased turtlebot but there is only one power output. In the wiring tutorial for the the turtlebot arm it shows a power board+ that has three outputs the presumably correspond to the three breakers in the turtlebot dashboard. I cannot find any information on building my own or purchasing a power board+. Do these exist? If not what would be the best way to go about powering the arm from the turtlebot?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/46703/turtlebot-output-power/) by [nickdf](https://answers.ros.org/users/3463/nickdf/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-10-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't believe the Powerboard+ was ever produced.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-03-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0